# How does (+ (-(*))4 5) evaluate to 8

Tags: scheme, racket

I am very new to scheme and am learning the basics right now. I understand that in `(+ 1 2)` + is like a function taking two inputs and returning the output. My quiz had a the question `(+ (-(*))4 5)` . According to DrRacket the answer is 8 but i am having a hard time understanding why it is the case. So I need help in understanding how the given expression evaluates to 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*) evaluates to 1

so (+ (-1) 4 5) is the sum of (-1) + (4) + (5)  which is 8

Comment: @danny If you want to know why `(*)` is 1 and why `(+)` is 0 go to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30467726/23567

Comment: Thank you.. This is very helpful